# SQL stacking results in a group for HTML Table in a single line

Tags: php, sql, post

I have a php program that inserts values from SMS messages coming in via HTTP POST to a database. The incoming messages are stored into $Body variable. I'm trying to make a HTML table that shows the table having one entry and grouping by the incoming number. Here is the code that inserts the entry to the database:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (stristr($Body, '1A') !== false || stristr($Body, '1B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '2A') !== false || stristr($Body, '2B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '3A') !== false || stristr($Body, '3B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '4A') !== false || stristr($Body, '4B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '5A') !== false || stristr($Body, '5B') !== false){
$sql = "INSERT INTO Lunch_Database (fromnum, tonum, sms_order, sms_table, 
sms_sid)
VALUES ( '$From' , '$To' , '' , '$Body' , '$SmsSid')";
}

if (stristr($Body, 'fish') !== false || stristr($Body, 'beef') !== false || 
stristr($Body, 'chicken') !== false ){
$sql = "INSERT INTO Lunch_Database (fromnum, tonum, sms_order, sms_table, 
sms_sid)
VALUES ( '$From' , '$To' , '$Body' , '' , '$SmsSid')";
}


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
//echo "New record created successfully"; echo can't work with sending SMS
} else {
//echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
$intro = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Response>
<Sms>Hey there, Welcome to Avaya Cloud Whats4Lunch application. What would 
you like for lunch? Please reply with Fish, Chicken or Beef</Sms>
</Response>";

$rownum = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Response>
<Sms>Which row number and letter are you in? Ex. 5A or 5B</Sms>
</Response>";

$thanks = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Sms>Thank you, your lunch order has been submitted.</Sms>
</Response>';

if (stristr($Body, 'lunch') !== false){
print $intro;
}
if (stristr($Body, 'fish') !== false || stristr($Body, 'beef') !== false || 
stristr($Body, 'chicken') !== false ){
print $rownum;
}
if (stristr($Body, '1A') !== false || stristr($Body, '1B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '2A') !== false || stristr($Body, '2B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '3A') !== false || stristr($Body, '3B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '4A') !== false || stristr($Body, '4B') !== false || 
stristr($Body, '5A') !== false || stristr($Body, '5B') !== false){
print $thanks;
}
```

After the entire SMS interaction this inserts this into the database from one person:[image]

What I want is all my entries to be saved on the same line in the database.

SELECT * FROM Lunch_Database GROUP BY fromnum should show one line with both sms_order and sms_table and collect them together.

UPDATE: I have no choice but to insert the rows separately as SMS messages are received to the $Body variable. I want to merge content from each row to make one row.

Let me know if this is possible.
Thanks,
Phillip K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're inserting two separate rows when what you want to do is insert a new row once, then modify the existing row on the second pass.

That would look something like

`UPDATE Lunch_Database SET sms_table = :table WHERE fromnum = :phone_num`

This way, instead of ignoring the previous entry, we search for it to update the previously created entry. Also, you may need to add more columns to the database; if the user returns for another meal, the system would assume the previous order information. This might manifest as a field to retain order time as a form of session.

You should seriously consider scrapping the `mysqli_query` and go for [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). If nothing else, use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). At the moment, it looks like your setup would be open to sql injection.

Comment: I don't have a choice. It has to be seperate rows because the rows are created as SMS messages are received. Is there anyway to merge content from one row to the other?

Comment: Yes, you could delete one and modify the other. But would still require the ability to track the rows anyway, meaning you'd be better off just updating the old row. Looking at your file, you clearly can choose to not just insert the information blindly. How can you say you have no choice? You would replace the INSERT with the UPDATE

Comment: Thanks. When I replied back I did notice the "UPDATE" query. Your solution worked perfectly